# Validation incorrect HTML 5

Tags: html, w3c

I would like to validate my site but find myself W3C errors,[look](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.les-petites-annonces-sarthoises.com/index.php)
**the shape attribute on the a element is obsolete. Use area instead of a for image maps**
How to fix these errors?

```
<ul>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(11)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-11-Allonnes.htm">ALLONNES  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(23)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-23-Ballon.htm">BALLON  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(14)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-14-Beaumont-sur-Sarthe.htm">BEAUMONT-SUR-SARTHE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(30)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-30-Bonnetable.htm">BONNETABLE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(28)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-28-Bouloire.htm">BOULOIRE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(2)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-2-Brulon.htm">BRULON  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(26)"  onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-26-Chateau-du-Loir.htm">CHÂTEAU-DU-LOIR  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">3 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(13)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-13-Conlie.htm">CONLIE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(18)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-18-Ecommoy.htm">ECOMMOY  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(5)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-5-Fresnay-sur-Sarthe.htm">FRESNAY-SUR-SARTHE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(31)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-31-La-Chartre-sur-le-Loir.htm">LA CHARTRE-SUR-LE-LOIR  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">5 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(36)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-36-La-Ferte-Bernard.htm">LA FERTE-BERNARD  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(8)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-8-la-fleche.htm">LA FLECHE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(7)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-7-La-Fresnaye-sur-Chedouet.htm">LA FRESNAYE-SUR-CHEDOUET  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(10)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-10-La-Suze-sur-Sarthe.htm">LA SUZE-SUR-SARTHE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(27)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-27-Le-Grand-Luce.htm">LE GRAND-LUCE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(16)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-16-Le-Lude.htm">LE LUDE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(39)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-39-Le-Mans-Centre.htm">LE MANS Centre  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(21)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-21-Le-Mans-Est-Campagne.htm">LE MANS Est-Campagne  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(22)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-22-Le-Mans-Nord-Campagne.htm">LE MANS Nord-Campagne  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(12)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-12-Le-Mans-Nord-Ouest.htm">LE MANS Nord-Ouest  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(40)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-40-Le-Mans-Nord-Ville.htm">LE MANS Nord-Ville  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(37)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-37-Le-Mans-Ouest.htm">LE MANS Ouest  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(20)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-20-Le-Mans-Sud-Est.htm">LE MANS Sud-Est  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(19)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-19-Le-Mans-Sud-Ouest.htm">LE MANS Sud-Ouest  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(38)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-38-Le-Mans-Ville-Est.htm">LE MANS Ville-Est  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(3)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-3-Loue.htm">LOUE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(9)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-9-Malicorne-sur-Sarthe.htm">MALICORNE-SUR-SARTHE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(15)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-15-Mamers.htm">MAMERS  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(24)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-24-Marolles-les-Braults.htm">MAROLLES-LES-BRAULTS  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(25)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-25-Mayet.htm">MAYET  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(29)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-29-Montfort-le-Gesnois.htm">MONTFORT-LE-GESNOIS  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(35)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-35-Montmirail.htm">MONTMIRAIL  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(17)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-17-Pontvallain.htm">PONTVALLAIN  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">1 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(1)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-1-Sable-sur-Sarthe.htm">SABLE-SUR-SARTHE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(32)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-32-St-Calais.htm">SAINT-CALAIS  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(6)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-6-St-Paterne.htm">SAINT-PATERNE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(4)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-4-Sille-le-Guillaume.htm">SILLE-LE-GUILLAUME  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(34)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-34-Tuffe.htm">TUFFE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
            <li><a onmouseover="MapReg(33)" onmouseout="MapRegSup();" shape="poly" href="Petites-annonces-33-Vibraye.htm">VIBRAYE  <span class="xd_vert_n_a">0 annonce(s)</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Use area instead of a for image maps.

Answer (score 0):

Clients should see your webpage correctly, even if you'd ignore that error. If you'd like to fix it, read: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: It's just not modern HTML5 code. Browsers support also previous versions of HTML. If you'd leave it as it is, browsers would show it correctly. If you'd like to modernize this page, follow the link above.

Comment: Attribute 'shape' in <a> is no longer supported in HTML5. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: Ok but me i want the clickable link of law is linked with the card left so I am forced to put a <a> </ a>?

Comment: Right now your page is HTML4 compliant. If you need to upgrade it to HTML5, you'd have to write this functionality (clickable link of law, with the card on the left), using <map> and <area> tags. Function MapReg most probably would need to be updated too, as well as CSS. So you need to chose: either you have your page in HTML4 format (shown correctly even on older browsers) or you rewrite those parts as requrested by HTML5 (and have no HTML5 validation errors). You may leave it as it is.